# why is isnumeric isdigit and isdecimal False for 1.5?

Tags: python, isnumeric

```
lst = ['a: 12', 'b: 1.5', 'c: 13']

for lines in lst:
    entry = lines.split(":")
    category = entry[0]
    amount = entry[1].strip()
    print(amount.isnumeric())
```

Result is True, False, True for isnumeric, isdigit, and isdecimal

eventually used isinstance(float(amount), float) to test for this case

Comment: Because `.` is not numeric.

Comment: Because ``.`` is not numeric, a digit, nor decimal.

Comment: then what's the best way to return true for a number like 1.5?

Comment: That depends on what you consider "a number like 1.5". Would you consider ``.1`` or ``1.`` numbers like it? What about ``1E9``? Are ``inf`` and ``nan`` numbers like it?

Answer (score 2):

The `isnumeric()` method returns `True` if all the characters are numeric `(0-9)`, otherwise `False`.

Exponents, like `²` and `¾` are also considered to be numeric values.

`-1` and `1.5` are **NOT considered** numeric values, because all the characters in the string must be numeric, and the `-` and the `.` are not.

Answer (score 1):

From Programiz "The `isnumeric()` method returns `True` if all characters in a string are numeric characters. If not, it returns `False`."

So, the point is not numeric.